# Active/Passive Thunderbolt 3 to HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, thunderbolt

I have a 2019 MacBook Pro 16" that has four thunderbolt 3 ports. Currently I have three cheap-o USB C to HDMI adapters that work well, but I feel like there is a drag on my system resources.

My question: is there an adapter that is preferred to allow the native Thunderbolt -> HDMI to pass through? I am fairly certain that those $20 dongles from Amazon are using the CPU in order to do the display output (are these considered active?).

According to the Thunderbolt website https://thunderbolttechnology.net/tech/faq, Thunderbolt natively supports Display Port. If I were to get a passive Thunderbolt 3 cable to Display Port, then get a DisplayPort to HDMI converter (my monitor doesn't have Display Port) would this work without taxing the CPU?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the model of your monitor ?

Comment: Sceptre E248W-19203R  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0773ZY26F/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 I plan on getting some 4K ones eventually

Comment: What resources are being over-used and by how much? What are you running over the three external monitors, a game?

Comment: Scratch the part about taxing the CPU. I just want 3 monitors, power, and USB devices (mouse keyboard) with one wire.

Answer (score 2):

The inexpensive adapters you have use [HDMI Alt Mode for USB Type-C](https://www.hdmi.org/spec/typec). They basically tell your Mac's Thunderbolt 3 / USB Type-C port to directly output HDMI signals over their high-speed data line pairs. This has no performance impact on your CPU or GPU over any other solutions that pipe your internal GPU's output through that port.

You mentioned three adapters. If you're using them all at the same time, then any performance degradation you feel may just be your GPU struggling to push out that many pixels. If that's the case, you might want to look into a Thunderbolt 3 based eGPU to take the load off your internal GPU.

Comment: Alright.... thanks... However I am looking for a one cable solution. So would these work with a thunderbolt dock as specified above?

Comment: @JeffreyKevinPry There are ways to do one-cable solutions to drive multiple displays from Thunderbolt 3, but only for Thunderbolt or DisplayPort displays, and only ones with support for multi-stream transport (MST), which seems pretty rare to me. Oh, and there are limits to the resolutions and framerates the displays can support when daisy-chaining from a single Thunderbolt 3 port. But that's a whole different question, which you should probably post as a separate Question post.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to connect three monitors with one cable, but that needs
[DisplayPort daisy-chaining](https://www.dell.com/support/article/fr-fr/sln293813/how-to-daisy-chain-multiple-monitors-using-displayport-multi-stream-transport-mst?lang=en).
Unfortunately, your monitors are using HDMI, so this solution does not
apply here.
DisplayPort daisy-chaining needs three monitors that have two
DisplayPort ports, ports for both input and output.

If you would like to connect your three HDMI monitors with one cable from the
MacBook, you would need a dock.
USB-C Docks that have three output HDMI ports are rare and not cheap.

For example see the
[UtrecSmart USB C Hub](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TXTF2WR).

Answer (score 1):

Good practical question; Strictly pass-through adapters/ connectors don't adjust/etc the signal, and aren't considered 'active': signals are simply passed through. However,  inclusion of the connectors can attenuate the signals, as can increases of cable lengths. So, additional connectors & lengths are to be avoided, and good high quality cables and good high quality connectors yield less loss. A hub effectively inserts additional cable length(however short) and two additional connectors into the signal path: which will attenuate signal.

Very high quality cables & connectors which are as short as is convenient per monitor may help, and could help offset the inclusion of a hub. Higher quality & shorter(yet convenient) length cable per each individual monitor might improve performance, and then using a hub for other devices might yield a good result, without going into specialised equipment(which still would be affected by attenuations due to connectors & cable lengths etc). Adequately driving three monitors uses significantly more GPU processing than adequately driving one monitor uses.

Also, some fairly inexpensively priced adapters might be of fairly good quality, but simply be priced relatively inexpensively. And part of the cost of some hubs etc is from them having higher quality connector components, and having higher quality(even if short) cable.